# Java 8 collection.stream() API in android

Tags: java, android, java-8

As per the [doc](https://developer.android.com/preview/j8-jack.html), android supports java 8 Stream functionality, but the below code is not working for me

```
ArrayList<Student> students= new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> idList = students.stream().map(Student::getId).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It gives cannot resolve method `stream()` error.

I have enabled the java 8 in my project

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```

Is android not supporting the `Collection.stream()` API yet?

Comment: Are you compiling using jack?  For Android N?

Comment: @LouisWasserman Oops. I was not aware that it is supported only from android N. Thanks for the info. Thanks for the info.